# SpringBoot beanFactory.getBean(PlatformTransactionManager.class) is very slow

Tags: java, spring-boot, grpc-java

springboot auto config `TransactionManager` and `SqlFactory`, it works well ,but when i use `@Transactional` the program wait in a daze, i flow the code and find 
`beanFactory.getBean(PlatformTransactionManager.class)` is very slow. 
but when i add this:

```
@Autowired
private PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager;
```

it works. so what's the problem. i have no idea, and i'm using grpc with springboot now, please help thx;

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(value = "cn.com.autohome.autopay.wallet")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true, exposeProxy = true)
public class AppMain extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppMain.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(AppMain.class);
    }
}

@Configuration
@MapperScan(basePackages = "cn.com.autohome.autopay.wallet.core.dal.mapper")
@ImportResource(locations = {"classpath:wallet-dal-bean.xml"})
public class WalletMyBatisConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataBaseProperties dataBaseProperties;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "walletDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.druid")
    public DataSource masterDataSource() throws SQLException {
        DruidDataSource dataSource = DruidDataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(dataBaseProperties.getWallet_data_source_driver_class());
        dataSource.setUrl(dataBaseProperties.getWallet_data_source_url());
        dataSource.setUsername(dataBaseProperties.getWallet_data_source_username());
        dataSource.setPassword(dataBaseProperties.getWallet_data_source_password());
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: What code is doing `beanFactory.getBean(PlatformTransactionManager.class)` unless it is framework code that shouldn't be done.

Comment: is the source code in spring-tx   TransactionAspectSupport, protected PlatformTransactionManager determineTransactionManager(TransactionAttribute txAttr) {}